# Homological dimension of categories of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring. We have two categories:

(a) category of $A$-modules
(b) category of finite type $A$-modules.

Do their homological dimensions agree? The homological dimension of an abelian category $C$ is defined as $\inf\{m \ | \ \text{Ext}^{m+1}_C(-,-)=0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both homological dimensions agree.

First, by Baer's criterion for injectivity, for any $A$-module $M$ you have $$\text{injdim}_A(M)=\max\{n\ |\ \text{Ext}^n_A(A/I,M)\neq 0\text{ for some }I\},$$ so you may restrict to finitely generated modules in the first argument when defining the homological dimension. For finitely generated modules $M$ (over a Noetherian ring), however, $\text{Ext}(M,-)$ commutes with directed colimits, so it also suffices to consider finitely generated modules in the second argument.

**Previous** The question has changed completely, the rest is the answer to the question of whether $\text{Ext}$ commutes with directed limits in the first and second argument.

No, this is not possible in either argument.

Concerning a direct limit in the second argument, it is not even true that $$\text{Hom}(M,\text{colim}_I N_i)\cong\text{colim}_I(M,N_i).$$ As an example, consider ${\mathbb Q} = \text{colim}({\mathbb Z}\xrightarrow{\cdot 2} {\mathbb Z}\xrightarrow{\cdot 3} \ \ldots)$: you have $\text{Hom}({\mathbb Q}, {\mathbb Z})=0$ but $\text{Hom}({\mathbb Q},{\mathbb Q})\neq 0$. The modules $M$ for which $\text{Hom}(M,-)$ commutes with directed limits are the finitely presented ones.

Concerning a direct limit in the first argument, you have the desired property for $\text{Hom}$, but not for $\text{Ext}$, since inverse limits are not exact. Concretely, any non-projective but flat module gives an example, since any flat module is the colimit of a diagram of free modules; again, ${\mathbb Q}$ as a ${\mathbb Z}$-module is an example.